# How to duplicate a spreadsheet from a template and get new spreadsheet's ID?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to create a function where I duplicate a spreadsheet from a template that is already in my Google Drive.

**Example:**

In the spreadsheet folder, I have the "Template" Worksheet and the "Main" Worksheet, in the main worksheet I want to put a button that when pressed it creates a copy of the template worksheet inside the same folder, named "TEST", and If possible I would also like to get the created Worksheet ID.

**Comments:**
The Main worksheet differs from the Template Worksheet.

Comment: question is offtopic because its simply a specification. to be on topic show all your research, attempts and what's failing after looking at the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can add button in your 'main' spreadsheet by going to insert->drawing. Once you've drawn and saved your button, click a small dropdown type icon on that drawing and click assign script and write your function's name only and it will run that function whenever that button/drawing is clicked.

[image]

Secondly, you can write this line to create a copy as well as get its ID:

```
var ID = DriveApp.getFileById("SOURCE_FILE").makeCopy("TEST", DriveApp.getFolderById("YOUR_DESTINATION_FOLDER")).getId();
```

Comment: Works fine! Concise and precise.

Comment: It works fine, can I get the ID of the new worksheet created?

Comment: yup, that getId() will save new sheet's ID in "ID" variable. You can log it using Logger.log(ID) if you want.